# pd.insert ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, valueerror

I have the following dataset(sample):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1':['Region1 (Y0001)','Region2 (Y0002)',
                       'Region3 (Y0003)','Region4 (Y0004)','Region5 (Y0005)'],
              'col_2':np.arange(1,6),
              'col_3':np.arange(6,11),
              'col_4':np.arange(11,16)})
```

NOTE: I had to change the real values, but the data types and structure are the same.

I can't get a hold of this error I get when using `pd.insert()`.

```
df.insert(df.columns.get_loc('col_1'),
      'new_col',
      df['col_1'].str.extract(r'\((\w+)\)'))
```

I checked the correct functioning of `pd.insert()` by running the following, and it worked!

```
df.insert(0,'Random_Col',55)
```

As far as I can tell, this error came up after I upgraded pandas to 1.4.3; I didn't have this issue before. However, this doesn't explain why the above check was executed flawlessly.

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Can you post an example of your dataframe so we can attempt to reproduce the error?

Comment: sure, apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DataFrame.insert](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) expects 3 positional arguments. `loc` which is an int, `column` which is a valid column name, and `value` which is either a single value or 1 dimensional data (*e.g.* Series or array-like).

Currently (pandas 1.4.3) [str.extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) returns a DataFrame by default:

```
df['col_1'].str.extract(r'\((\w+)\)')

       0
0  Y0001
1  Y0002
2  Y0003
3  Y0004
4  Y0005
```

The error message:

> ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)

is indicating that a 2-dimensional structure (a DataFrame) was provided as the `value` to `insert` which is 1 dimension more than the expected.

---

There are a few options to fix this.

1. Since there is a single capture group we can stop the output from expanding into a DataFrame with `expand=False`

```
df.insert(
    df.columns.get_loc('col_1'),
    'new_col',
    df['col_1'].str.extract(r'\((\w+)\)', expand=False)
)
```

OR

2. Select a column from the output. In this case column 0.

```
df.insert(
    df.columns.get_loc('col_1'),
    'new_col',
    df['col_1'].str.extract(r'\((\w+)\)')[0]  # Get capture group (column) 0
)
```

Either option produces `df`:

```
  new_col            col_1  col_2  col_3  col_4
0   Y0001  Region1 (Y0001)      1      6     11
1   Y0002  Region2 (Y0002)      2      7     12
2   Y0003  Region3 (Y0003)      3      8     13
3   Y0004  Region4 (Y0004)      4      9     14
4   Y0005  Region5 (Y0005)      5     10     15
```